# pygame screen not showing anything

Tags: python, pygame

I am writing a space shooter program in Python using pygame library.But the display is not showing anything that i programmed to display. There is nothing appears to wrong with the code. Here is the main file.

```
import sys
import pygame
import bullet
from settings import Setting
from ship import Ship
from pygame.sprite import Group
import functions as gf

def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    gmSet = Setting()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((gmSet.screen_w, gmSet.screen_h))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
    bg_color = gmSet.bg_color

    ship = Ship(screen)
    bullets = Group()

    while True:
        gf.check_events(ship, gmSet, screen, bullets)
        bullets.update()
        for bullet in bullets.copy():
            if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
                bullets.remove(bullet)
        print(len(bullets))
        gf.update_screen(gmSet, screen, ship, bullets)
        
        
run_game()
```

Here is the `update_screen` function.

```
def update_screen(settings, screen, ship, bullets):
    screen.fill(settings.bg_color)
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    ship.place()
```

Python is not giving any error when it runs and I can say that the program is not stuck in a while loop either. **Let me know if I've given only limited information**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the display.
You are actually drawing on a [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) object. If you draw on the *Surface* associated to the PyGame display, this is not immediately visible in the display. The changes become visibel, when the display is updated with either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip).

See [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip):

> This will update the contents of the entire display.

Call `pygame.display.flip()` either in the `update_screen` function or at the end of the application loop:

```py
while True:
    gf.check_events(ship, gmSet, screen, bullets)
    bullets.update()
    for bullet in bullets.copy():
        if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
            bullets.remove(bullet)
    print(len(bullets))
    gf.update_screen(gmSet, screen, ship, bullets)
        
    pygame.display.flip()    # <---
```